# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error occured when using stringWithFormat

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, exc-bad-access

this is my header section:

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString *status_id;
}
```

in the controller file, i am assigning the variable:

```
- (void)updateStatus
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/RightNow/API/status.json"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request startSynchronous];
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSString *response = [NSString alloc];

    NSError *error2;
    NSData* data = [response dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data      options:kNilOptions error:&error2];
    status_id = [json objectForKey:@"id"];
}
```

now, when i try to use the status_id again, i get the error

```
- (IBAction)likeClick:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/RightNow/API/vote"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setPostValue:status_id forKey:@"id"]; //The error comes here
    [request setPostValue:@"like" forKey:@"vote"];
    [request startSynchronous];
}
```

sorry about my bad english.
please help me, thank you!

Comment: I think this may mean your status_ID is null.

Comment: @Benny, i tried to assign it... what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[json objectForKey:@"id"]; will return the object in autorelease pool. You either need to send a copy message to it like

```
status_id = [[json objectForKey:@"id"] copy];
```

and release it when appropriate (if not using ARC)